# Excel AVERAGEIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet in WB1 that looks like this:

```
       A            B            C
Row    Supplier     PO_Date      Delivery_Days
... 
2091   A            8/2/2018     5
2092   B            8/5/2018     4
2093   C            8/7/2018     1
2094   B            8/8/2018     
2095   B            8/8/2018     -7
2096   B            8/8/2018     -7
2097   C            8/17/2018     5
2098   D            8/22/2018     
2099   D            8/22/2018    2
2100   A            8/28/2018    -3
2101   E            8/30/2018    4
2102   A            8/31/2018
2103   A            8/31/2018    12
...
```

And in WB2, I have a cell that is meant to calculate the average delivery days, but only including specific suppliers and adjustable start and end dates in cells B1 and B2. That function looks like this:

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS('[WB1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$C:$C,
'[WB1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$A:$A, {"A", "B", "C"},
'[WB1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$B:$B,">=" & B1,
'[WB1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$B:$B,"<=" & B2))
```

This function does not produce the value I want, though. I want to calculate the average delivery days for all the POs from these specific suppliers, not the average of the average delivery days for the POs for each supplier. (Basically, I want to sum up all the Delivery Days ONCE, not sum and divide within each supplier, then sum and divide those averages.)

How do I need to change the formula? Or should I use a different formula all together?

Comment: Have you tried removing the outer `AVERAGE` function?

Comment: Yes. This only gives me the average Delivery Days for the first supplier listed, Supplier "A".

Comment: If an array is returned to a single cell, only the first value is visible. Do you already have a column of unique suppliers, which this formula will go next to?

Comment: have you tried `sumifs()` then `countifs()` so you divide those to get your average, ensuring only one division?

Comment: @Mistella I am trying to get it all to just go into one cell, so while I do have a column of unique suppliers, I don't necessarily want to present information next to it.

Comment: @Cyril Hadn't thought of that, but just implemented it and it's working great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

posting comment as answer so this can be marked appropriately in the queue:

```
have you tried sumifs() then countifs() so you divide those to get your average, ensuring only one division? – Cyril 31 mins ago 

@Cyril Hadn't thought of that, but just implemented it and it's working great. Thank you. – Millie 15 mins
```